# Economy of words is part of the English language way (which) is saying things

Tags: relative-clauses

"Economy of words is part of the English language way is saying things! Passive voice and complex sentences are out!"

When analyzing the sentence above, I found it has one subject, but has two finite verbs "is" and "say": "{Economy of words} {is} {part of the English language way} {is saying} {things}!"

What about saying it as "{Economy of words} {is} {part of the English language way} {which} {is saying} {things}!"

Comment: The sentence does not seem to have been produced by a native speaker. It has errors and is not idiomatic. It defies analysis.

Comment: The first sentence is, frankly, hardly a sentence. The second use of the verb _is_  has no place there and simply is not English syntax. You could stop the sentence after the word _language_, and you would have a complete sentence that gets the message across perfectly well. If you absolutely insist on keeping something similar to what you have now, you could have this: _Economy of words is part of the English language's way of saying things._ But it's not the best style and doesn't sound very good.

Comment: The sentence isn't really as incomprehensible as the comments are making it out to be. Consider just a few changes. ***That*** *economy of words is part of the English language [] is saying* ***something***. To me, the biggest problem is the use of **things**. The idiom is *(that's) saying* ***something***, not *(that's) saying things.*

Comment: The first sentence is ungrammatical, and the second dubious, twinning an anarthrous non-count usage with a count usage. 'Economy of words is part of the way the English language has of saying things!' Still clumsy and ironic. _English is economical._